# In ruby ensure only certain methods are available

Tags: ruby, dsl

I was reading an [article](https://medium.com/@farsi_mehdi/parsing-a-dsl-in-ruby-in-less-that-30-loc-2c651a3f2e19) on how to build a simple DSL and parse the file but it does (and rightfully so) point out how dangerous this is as you can't really trust what get's eval'ed.

So it got me thinking, is it possible to make it safe?

To that end, **is it possible to ensure that within the execution context, only the methods of the DSL (and what's specifically been allowed) are available and that calls to other things will just not do anything or error?**

The code used in the example is:

```rb
class OrdersDsl
  def initialize
    @orders = { to_perform: [], to_schedule: [] }.freeze
  end

  def parse(order_filename)
    instance_eval File.read(order_filename)
  end

  private

  def order_now(order_name, *order_options)
    @orders[:to_perform] << serialize_order(order_name, *order_options)
  end

  def schedule(order_name, *order_options)
    @orders[:to_schedule] << serialize_order(order_name, *order_options)
  end

  def serialize_order(name, *options)
    [name, *options]
  end

  def OrdersDsl.run(order_filename = 'Orders')
    OrdersDsl.new.parse(order_filename)
  end
end
```

Comment: Not without parsing the code using a lexer (ripper, ruby_parser, ...).